# Can I connect Unity and Pyramid APEX 7000 Bill Acceptor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hardware

I am developing one game application using Unity Engine, In which I need to connect Pyramid APEX 7000 Bill Acceptor and Unity. So How can I connect them? Recently I can connect it but it stays only 3 or 4 seconds connection then it disabled blue lights from Acceptor. Can any one help me out how to check how much money I have inserted in Bill Acceptor through code from Unity only?

Comment: You would need to check with the apex docs, there are bound to be either api's or rules you need to follow to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

actually I checked docs for it and I applied the same in Unity but it says that API is not directly support Mono in Unity.